# Change of variables FPE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given the partial differential equation:

$$\partial_tP(z,t)=-\partial_z[(-z^2+A)P(z,t)]+D\partial_{zz}P(z,t)$$
where $A$ and $D$ are constant parameters.

how to remove $z^2$ term by substitution?